# How to view local PDF file in angular?

Tags: angular, pdf-viewer

I am taking a PDF file as the input.

I want to display this selected PDF on the browser. PDF File is stored in my laptop downloads section.

How to do display this local PDF?
I am using n-g-2 PDF-viewer to display the PDF.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Pls share the code that you have tried

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `pdf-viewer` inside your template:

```
<pdf-viewer
    [src]="pdfSrc"
    [render-text]="true"
    style="display: block;"
></pdf-viewer>
```

You can capture the file input change after choosing a file

```
<input (change)="onFileSelected()" type="file" id="file">
```

and implement the onFileSelected() method inside your class:

```
export class AppComponent {
    pdfSrc: string;

    onFileSelected() {
        let $img: any = document.querySelector('#file');
      
        if (typeof (FileReader) !== 'undefined') {
            let reader = new FileReader();
        
            reader.onload = (e: any) => {
                this.pdfSrc = e.target.result;
            };
        
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer($img.files[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

See **Render local PDF file** section in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer).